# Using a sort of portable JDK on centOs

Tags: centos, java-8, environment-variables

This is the first time that I use linux in my life, I'm a little bit strugling.
Permissions, user, folder structure, it's a lot to take in.

Everything I did, I did with the ATH user which is a regular non sudoer user.

I got Centos minimal and put it in a VM

then I extracted the linux tar.gz jdk in /home/ath/monitoring/jdk1.8.0_70_linux64

And I added this to a sh script, this sh script call other sh script
I want them to only use this jdk

below #!/bin/sh I added

export JAVA_HOME=/home/ath/monitoring/jdk1.8.0_70_linux64

However when I launch the script I get :

Which : no java in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ath.local/bin:/home/ath/bin)
Could not find any executable java binary. Please install java in your PATH or set JAVA_HOME

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

ps : I used (logged as root) chmod +x /home/ath/monitoring/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch.sh
on the sh script otherwhise it would not run

Answer (score 0):

So I also had to add this line because the script was looking into PATH :

```
export JAVA_HOME PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

And I had to render all the file in jdk/bin executable running this inside

```
chmod a+x *
```

I don't get it tho, each time I'm getting a software I have to manually go and chmod every file that need it? quite bothersome.